# What is the return type of a MembershipUserCollection.GetEnumerator();

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I need help understanding this

In my controller I have

```
MembershipUserCollection usersObj = Membership.GetAllUsers();
IEnumerator<MembershipUserCollection> model = usersObj.GetEnumerator();
return PartialView(model );
```

I need an `IEnumerator object` to iterate through but I am not sure which type of `IEnumerator` `MembershipUserCollection.GetEnumerator()` returns.

I want to pass this `IEnumerator` to a view and there I´ll use this `Enumerator` inside of a `foreach`:

```
 @foreach (var membershipUser in Model.getEnumerator())
 { ... }
```

Comment: just return the collection. why do you want the enumerator? anyway you can always check using the debugger or just click F12 on the 'GetEnumerator' method to see what is the return type.

Comment: If `IEnumerator<MembershipUserCollection> model = ...` doesn't complain at you, looks like you have an `Enumerator` over a `MembershipUserCollection`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GetEnumerator() Returns an enumerator that iterates through a collection.

Collection must meet the following requirements:

```
The collection type:
    1. Must be one of the types: interface, class, or struct.
    2. Must include an instance method named GetEnumerator that returns a type, for example, Enumerator.

The type Enumerator (a class or struct) must contain:
   1. A property named Current that returns ItemType or a type that can be converted to it. The property accessor returns the current element of the collection.
```

for more information see the link below:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable.getenumerator.aspx

Comment: Compiler Error Message: CS1579: foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type System.Collections.IEnumerator because System.Collections.IEnumerator does not contain a public definition for GetEnumerator. How comes if this is the main purpose of IEnumerator?

Comment: you need to iterate using foreach(var item in itemtype). since GetEnumerator returns a collection of a specific type

Answer (score 4):

Your question assumes incorrectly that this code works:

```
@foreach (var membershipUser in Model.getEnumerator()) { ... }
```

In fact, you should write this:

```
@foreach (var membershipUser in Model) { ... }
```

With that, your entire question becomes moot.  The compiler handles the details of calling `GetEnumerator`, and, as you've used the `var` keyword, it infers the type of the loop variable, too.

Answer (score 0):

`foreach` iterates throught objects that inherits from the `IEnumerable` interface, so if `MembershipUserCollection` inherits from it (and [it does](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipusercollection.aspx)), you can pass it to the model and it should work.

```
MembershipUserCollection usersObj = Membership.GetAllUsers();
return PartialView(usersObj);
```

and in the view

```
@model System.Web.Security.MembershipUserCollection

<h2>Users</h2>
<ul>
    @foreach(var u in Model)
    {
        <li>u.UserName</li>
    }
</ul>
```

Comment: The problem is model MembershipUserCollection is not available, nor model System.Web.Security.MembershipUserCollection. That is why I am in doubt

Comment: You might need to provide the full namespace instead of just @model MembershipUserCollection